# How to connect two DBLookUpComboboxes that can be used as filter in Lazarus

Tags: delphi, combobox, lazarus

I have 2 tables: 1. **Projects**, 2. **Article_Weights**.
Table **Projects** is connected to first DBLookUpCombobox *DBLkpCbo_Projects*.
It has one column ***Project*** which contains four digit numbers. (1001, 1004, 1008,...)

Table **Article_Weights** containing columns ***Project***, ***Article_Number***, ***Article_Weights*** etc. This table is connected with DBLookUpCombobox *DBLkpCbo_Articles*.

What I want to achieve is when I choose from first combobox some project, second combobox will show just article numbers which belongs to that projects. After that when I choose some article number from second combobox, information about this article will be shown in DBGrid.

Filtering is working. I am stuck on last point. When I choose some article number I get error "Data types do not match in the expression criteria"

This is my code:

```
procedure TMainForm.DBLkpCbo_ProjectSelect(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if DBLkpCbo_Project.ItemIndex <> -1 then begin
    SQLQuery2.Active:=true;
    //SQLQuery1.ApplyUpdates();
    SQLTransaction1.Commit();
    SQLQuery2.Close;
    SQLQuery2.SQL.Text:='SELECT Article_Number FROM Article_Weights WHERE Project = '+DBLkpCbo_Project.Text+'';
    SQLQuery2.Open;
   end;
end;


procedure TMainForm.DBLkpCbo_ArticleChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if DBLkpCbo_Article.ItemIndex <> -1 then begin
    //DBGrid1.Enabled:=true;
    SQLQuery3.Active:=true;
    //SQLQuery1.ApplyUpdates();
    SQLTransaction1.Commit();
    SQLQuery3.Close;
    SQLQuery3.SQL.Text:='SELECT Article_Number FROM Article_Weights WHERE Article_Number='+DBLkpCbo_Article.Text+'';
    SQLQuery3.Open;
  end;
end;
```

Thank you for any answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is Article_Number a text field or (as the name suggests) a numeric field? If it is a number is DBLkpCbo_Article.Text actually numeric (i.e. a string containing a valid number)? If, as I suspect, Article_Number is a text field, you have omitted the quotation marks:

```
SQLQuery3.SQL.Text:='SELECT Article_Number FROM Article_Weights WHERE Article_Number='''+DBLkpCbo_Article.Text+'''';
```

Comment: Article_Number is set in MS Access as short text and example looks like this: 1004.001.0020. I tryed your suggestion, but error message pops up: "Ensure that is not containing invalid characters or punctuation marks". When I tryed to rename it to "10040010020" I got error "Too few parameters".

Comment: Sorry - I used double quotes instead of single - been a while since I used SQL. Corrected now.

Comment: Its really working! :) I spented so much time trying to solving that issue. Thank you very much.